# How can I replace the slash in this string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a string like:
`images/Qcuj/lXOSWNDwF/FmSgCbQ==.jpg`

and I want to replace the `/` into `-` after `images/`

may the results like:

`images/Qcuj-lXOSWNDwF-FmSgCbQ==.jpg`

This seems simple but I have no clue, thanks for help!

---

the string may be in the html file,may like:

`<td><img src="images/Qcuj/lXOSWNDwF/FmSgCbQ==.jpg" ></td>`

how does this match and replace correctly?

thanks for everyone!! I'll comprehend the answers for a while!

By the way ,i use php.

Comment: Have you tried anything or did some research ?

Comment: the string is in a HTML file,so there may have lots of tags around it,not just match the given string.

Comment: how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for reminding,I'll read the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`\G`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) anchor to do a continuous pattern match.

The anchor \G matches at the position where the previous match ended.

```
(?:images/|(?<!^)\G)[^\n/]*\K/
```

Use the above regex and then replace the matched `/` with `-`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gL0jQ3/3)

```
$str = "images/Qcuj/lXOSWNDwF/FmSgCbQ==.jpg";
echo preg_replace('~(?:images/|(?<!^)\G)[^\n/]*\K/~', '-', $str);
```

**Output:**

```
images/Qcuj-lXOSWNDwF-FmSgCbQ==.jpg
```

Comment: the string may be in the html file,may like:`<td><img src="images/Qcuj/lXOSWNDwF/FmSgCbQ==.jpg" ></td>`, how does this match?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This works! ^_^  I don't have enough reputations to vote you,sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$s = 'images/Qcuj/lXOSWNDwF/FmSgCbQ==.jpg';
echo preg_replace('~(images/)(*SKIP)(*F)|([^/]*)/~', '$1$2-', $s);
images/Qcuj-lXOSWNDwF-FmSgCbQ==.jpg
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eP5xH6/2)

**Explanation:**

- `(*FAIL)` behaves like a failing negative assertion and is a synonym for `(?!)`
- `(*SKIP)` defines a point beyond which the regex engine is not allowed to backtrack when the subpattern fails later
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` together provide a nice alternative of restriction that you cannot have a variable length lookbehind in above regex.
- In this regex we match `image/` and skip+fail this match altogether. In the rest of the input we match `/` and replace by `-`.

---

**Update:** For updated regex you can use:

```
$s = '<td><img src="images/Qcuj/lXOSWNDwF/FmSgCbQ==.jpg" ></td>';
echo preg_replace('~(images/|</)(*SKIP)(*F)|([^/<"]*)/~', '$1$2-', $s);
<td><img src="images/Qcuj-lXOSWNDwF-FmSgCbQ==.jpg" ></td>
```

However I must caution on modifying HTML source using regex. Better you extract `src` part of the image using `DOM` and then apply this regex.

Comment: the string may be in the html file,may like:`<td><img src="images/Qcuj/lXOSWNDwF/FmSgCbQ==.jpg" ></td>`, how does this match and replace correctly?

Comment: **Modifying HTML using regex is dangerous and error prone**. Better you extract `src` part using DOM and then apply this regex.

Comment: If you have no option to use DOM then for your case [you can use this regex](https://regex101.com/r/eP5xH6/3)

Comment: Thank you very much!! Regex is so difficult and I have a long way to go

Answer (score 1):

Instead of jumping through hoops while pinching your nose at the same time to make it work with regular expressions, just split up the string first and apply the replacement only in the second portion:

```
$s = 'images/Qcuj/lXOSWNDwF/FmSgCbQ==.jpg';
list($prefix, $suffix) = explode('/', $s, 2);

$t = $prefix . '/' . strtr($suffix, '/', '-');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list($path, $rest) = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $s, 2);
echo $path . PATH_SEPARATOR . implode('-', explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $rest));
//⇒ images/Qcuj-lXOSWNDwF-FmSgCbQ==.jpg
```

Here we split the string to *path* and *the rest*, convert slashes in *the rest* and glue pieces back with a slash. Whether you can avoid using regexps, avoid it.

Comment: Oh i see, first version wasn't  :)